# I am having a school piano recital next week, and I need some advice on the program

Tags: piano, performing

Hello I am having a 30 minute recital at my school festival next week.

I was wondering if introducing and giving some background information on each piece would be a good idea for the recital. My piano teacher does that during his concerts, to not bore the audience and engage them. I am planning to do it between each piece that I play.

How brief should the introduction be? It is a simple, small scaled recital, would it be awkward to do so? I am in my senior years in high school.

Comment: Intros before pieces are fine; I'd also welcome them before the first piece and thank them before the last piece. 30-60 seconds intro. Tell a little relatable story or something relatable they listen for or think about as they listen to help them enjoy the piece.

Comment: An intro to a piece is a good idea.   Keep it short and stick to facts;  do not start giving opinions because you risk alienating some of your audience if they disagree with you.

Comment: you can also give a hand-out with some datas about the composer, the circumstances of the composition and 2-3 special features of the piece (form, motives, chords).

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea. At the beginning, introduce yourself, with perhaps one or two minutes of chat, thank the for attending, and name the first piece.

A brief explanation of a couple of the other pieces would be good, especially before any thought-provoking or atmospheric piece, setting the mood for your audience.

Don't talk in between every piece - after one, wait until the applause has finished, give yourself fifteen or so seconds before simply starting the next piece.

At the end, a brief thankyou is all you'll need to say. Consider whether an encore is appropriate, and have it ready just in case they won't let you go!